# Php ews Wrong Version

Tags: php, github, exchange-server, php-ews

Im using the php-ews script from [https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/wiki](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews/wiki/%22Github%22). If i run this script i always get a error message in the browser. It says

> not collected Exception: Wrong Version

Does anybody have an idea what to do?
(I load the autoloader with config.inc include and it works)

Exchange version 2010 SP1

```
    #include("../include/all_inc.inc");

    $server = "******";
    $username="******";
    $password="*****";
    $version =ExchangeWebServices::VERSION_2010;

    $ews = new ExchangeWebServices($server, $username, $password, $version);


    $request = new EWSType_FindFolderType();
    $request->Traversal = EWSType_FolderQueryTraversalType::SHALLOW;
    $request->FolderShape = new EWSType_FolderResponseShapeType();
    $request->FolderShape->BaseShape = EWSType_DefaultShapeNamesType::ALL_PROPERTIES;

    // configure the view
    $request->IndexedPageFolderView = new EWSType_IndexedPageViewType();
    $request->IndexedPageFolderView->BasePoint = 'Beginning';
    $request->IndexedPageFolderView->Offset = 0;

    // set the starting folder as the inbox
    $request->ParentFolderIds = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();
    $request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId = new EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdType();
    $request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Id = EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdNameType::INBOX;

    // make the actual call
    $response = $ews->FindFolder($request);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an explicit version constant for Exchange 2010 SP1 that you should use.

This should do it for you:

`$version = ExchangeWebServices::VERSION_2010_SP1;`